# Dynamics AX custom table synch error

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

At one time, I created some tables and views to support our custom AX code.  The code and tables have since been deleted, but I still receive synchronization errors on the AX data dictionary on those (non-existent) tables.

The table/views are gone from the AOT, they are not listed in the SQLDictionary table, they are not present in any layer, and they do not exist on the SQL Server database.  However, every time we synchronize, we still see the following sync errors (each on a different object, none of which exist):

```
- No runnable code in method 'computeLocationType' (searching the entire AOT for this method finds nothing
- Inconsistency in Microsoft Dynamics data dictionary
- The View could not be created in the database
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See contents of the [`SqlSyncInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sqlsyncinfo.aspx) table. Row with your view should be there and you can delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the assist.  I really appreciate it.